# Render buffer in Open GL ES on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, framebuffer

When drawing with Open GL ES one creates a framebuffer, attaches it to the context, creates a renderbuffer, attaches it to the context and, finally, attaches the renderbuffer to the framebuffer.

My question is: Why is it that the renderbuffer is bound twice? In Open GL all objects in use must be bound to the context, I get that. But it seems to me that the renderbuffer is already bound to the context indirectly via the framebuffer. So why attach it to the context directly? Or put differently: if we attach it to the context directly, why bind it to the framebuffer?

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to be bound twice. At least not in my project. The only place that is bound is before "framebuferrenderbuffer" function.